# Monitoring my REST API service

Tags: rest, web-services, monitoring

I have a REST API. I want to monitor it -- that it's always up.

That's the canonical way to ping it? Especially when all of its calls require an API key.

Should I create an empty open end point which returns "200 ok" specially for monitoring it?

Comment: In _The Art of Monitoring_, (Chapter 9.4) Turnball suggests creating a "/health" endpoint specifically for monitoring as the question asks.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @KevinO on what page?

Comment: I don't have a page number, as Kindle edition.

Comment: I can't find "/health" in the book

Comment: It is in chapter 9, section 4, "health checks, endpoints, and external monitoring"

Comment: And I guess the actual "/health" is implied, as it just writes of endpoints. The specific "/health" is in _Practical Monitoring_, chapter 2. But the concepts are laid out in Turnbull.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create an empty open end point which returns "200 ok" specially for monitoring it?

That's common: to provide to a monitoring service a bookmark that can be read (GET) to discover the health of the server.

There's no specific agreement on which resource should be used; which is to say there isn't anything like the [Robot Exclusion Standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) that says you must use a specific identifier for the resource.

The [Link Relations Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) doesn't include any links to direct a clients attention to a health check.

Nor is there any particular agreement on media type to be used to describe the health of the system in detail.  You might be able to leverage [Problem Details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807#section-3)?

Generic monitors aren't likely to look at the payload in any case, but rather just look information in the response headers, like the HTTP Status Code.  So you might find something like Consul, which treats 2xx as healthy, 429 as a warning, and [anything else as a failure](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html).

Using API Key as a parameter in a health check is a pattern I am not familiar with.  I would normally expect the health check to use an internal key, understood to be assigned to monitoring and operations.